# How to get UserName in the global.asax file in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to get `User.Identity.Name` in the application_start method in `global.asax` file. Is there any way to get `loggedInUserName` in this method. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Application_Start()` event fires before any user accesses the web application so it is not possible to retrieve `User.Identity` there.

Comment: yes .. i get this Application_AuthenticateRequest method. it works fine

Answer (score -1):

You can use `HttpCookies`:

```
HttpCookie settings = new HttpCookie("Conf");
settings["Username"] = user.Username.ToString();

settings.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
Response.Cookies.Add(settings);
```

Use this when you loggin to save logged user in cookies. And then you can use it wherever you want it, like this:

```
 @Request.Cookies["Conf"]["Username"]
```

Comment: When application starts then Application_Start methods gets execute and how i can get this username from the cookies..

Comment: Do you have login page? Does the user first must to login in, in some point? If you have, then this above can help you, with that you can have username on every page you want.

Comment: you are saying that i need to store in cookies in accountController from where i have login method

Comment: Yes. In accountControler in login method put that code above. And use it wherever you want with this:
@Request.Cookies["Conf"]["Username"]

Comment: jigsaw22 thanks a lot ..but as soon as the application starts it goes to the application_start method after that it goes to the login method in the Account Controller .. I need login in user name after authenticate the user .. is there any way.. plz help.

Comment: you must authenticate the user first, and then use the cookies if the user succesufully logged in. Make a method: 
bool IsValid(string _username, string _password) { Hint: find that user in databese, and if you find it, return true }

Then in accountController in login method first do this:

 if (IsValid(user.Username, user.Password)) { //rest of the code }